# Como Dar orden Especifico Namespace en XML / C#

Tags: c#, api, .net, xml

Neceito Generar un XML de Una forma sumamente Especifica ya que asi lo lee el sistema (Externo) que se encarga de timbrar este CFDI.
El XML Se genera atraves de una API y lo guarda en una ruta en especifico de la cual posteriormente el programa externo toma todos los XML formados en esa ruta y se encarga de timbrarlos, generar sus PDF's y Regresar el XML Sellado, Actualmente es el unico detalle que necesito corregir, si yo hago el cambio manualmente el de posiciones el sistema lo toma en cuenta y lo TIMBRA sin emanargo si no tiene ese orden e intento timbrarlo el programa surge error, por lo cual no es opcion dejarlo de esa manera y sugerir cambios al programa de sellado o algo por el estilo

```html
using APICfdi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CfdiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GenerarXml([FromBody] Comprobante modelo)
    {
        try
        {
            // Verificar que el modelo recibido no sea nulo
            if (modelo == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("El modelo no puede ser nulo.");
            }

            // Crear un objeto XmlSerializerNamespaces para manejar los namespaces
            var xmlNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            // Agrega los namespaces necesarios
            xmlNamespace.Add("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4");
            //xmlNamespace.Add("cartaporte20", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20"); //No usado Acutalmente para darle Orden Especifco SAT

            // Especificar la codificación UTF-8 explícitamente
            var utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, utf8Encoding))
                {
                    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                    // Serializar el objeto
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Comprobante));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, modelo, xmlNamespace);

                    // Reiniciar la posición del flujo para lectura
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    // Leer el XML desde el flujo
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                    {
                        // Obtener el XML como una cadena
                        var xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                        // Modificar el XML para agregar los atributos adicionales
                        xmlString = xmlString.Replace("<Comprobante ", "<cfdi:Comprobante ");
                        xmlString = xmlString.Replace("</Comprobante>", "</cfdi:Comprobante>");
                        xmlString = xmlString.Replace("<cfdi:Comprobante ", $"<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:cartaporte20=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd\" ");

                        // Guardar el XML en un archivo
                        var rutaArchivo = "C:/SDK/XMLs/CFDI_SDK.xml";
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(rutaArchivo, xmlString, utf8Encoding);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Ok("XML generado y guardado exitosamente.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Error al generar y guardar el XML: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo el XML resultado lo genera asi:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cartaporte20="http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd" Certificado="" Exportacion="01" Fecha="2023-09-12T15:53:53" Folio="95" LugarExpedicion="64346" Moneda="XXX" NoCertificado="" Sello="" Serie="CFDITRAS" SubTotal="0" TipoDeComprobante="T" Total="0" Version="4.0" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4">
```

Sin embargo necesito que orden sea, CFDI, XSI, CARTAPORTE20, SCHEMA como se muestra a continuación:

```html
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cartaporte20="http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd" Certificado="" Exportacion="01" Fecha="2023-09-12T15:53:53" Folio="95" LugarExpedicion="64346" Moneda="XXX" NoCertificado="" Sello="" Serie="CFDITRAS" SubTotal="0" TipoDeComprobante="T" Total="0" Version="4.0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta tiene un par de elementos extraños, pero vamos por partes

El orden de los `namespace` viene dado por el orden en que los agregas:

```
xmlNamespace.Add("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4");
xmlNamespace.Add("cartaporte20", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20");
xmlNamespace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlNamespace.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd");
```

Imprime

```html
<Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4"
xmlns:cartaporte20="http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4
http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd
http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20
http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd"
Certificado="" Exportacion="01" Fecha="2023-09-12T15:53:53" Folio="95"
LugarExpedicion="64346" Moneda="XXX" NoCertificado="" Sello=""
Serie="CFDITRAS" SubTotal="0" TipoDeComprobante="T" Total="0" Version="4.0" />
```

Tu problema es que la clase "Comprobante" debe ir con el prefijo del namespace y para esto debes agregar el atributo respecivo:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4")]
public class Comprobante 
{
  //ETC
}
```

Y cuando haces esto el `namespace` "cfdi" lo agrega al final

```html
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cartaporte20="http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd"
Certificado="" Exportacion="01" Fecha="2023-09-12T15:53:53" 
Folio="95" LugarExpedicion="64346" Moneda="XXX" NoCertificado="" Sello="" Serie="CFDITRAS" SubTotal="0" TipoDeComprobante="T" Total="0" Version="4.0"
xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" />
```

Para solventar esto, estas reescribiendo el XML como string usando replace. Y aquí viene lo primero que me resulta extraño de tu pregunta, si estas haciendo esto, **porque no simplemente los escribes en el orden que deseas y ya**

Es decir, comentas esta línea

```
//xmlNamespace.Add("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4");
```

Y luego haces:

```
xmlString = xmlString.Replace("<Comprobante ", "<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:cartaporte20=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd\" ");
xmlString = xmlString.Replace("</Comprobante>", "</cfdi:Comprobante>");
```

O más simple, escribes agregas los `namespace` como te muestro en el primer código y quitas el atributo de la clase

```
//[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4")] //quitamos esto
public class Comprobante 
{
```

Con esto solo debes reemplazar el `Comprobante` por `cfdi:Comprobante`

```
xmlString = xmlString.Replace("<Comprobante", "<cfdi:Comprobante").Replace("</Comprobante>", "</cfdi:Comprobante>");
```

O otra alternativa: Llegado al punto que estas editando el XML como string, quizas es mejor escribir una función en tu clase `Comprobante`

```
public class Comprobante 
{
  //Las propiedades de la clase

    public string ToXML()
    {
        return $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:cartaporte20=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd\" Certificado=\"{Certificado}\" Exportacion=\"{Exportacion}\" Fecha=\"{Fecha}\" Folio=\"{Folio}\" LugarExpedicion=\"{LugarExpedicion}\" Moneda=\"{Moneda}\" NoCertificado=\"{NoCertificado}\" Sello=\"{Sello}\" Serie=\"{Serie}\" SubTotal=\"{SubTotal}\" TipoDeComprobante=\"{TipoDeComprobante}\" Total=\"{Total}\" Version=\"{Version}\" >";
    }
}
```

---

Lo otro extraño de tu pregunta es que el orden de los atributos en un XML no importa salvo cuando se requiere [XML Canónico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML), que se usa justamente para firmar documentos, pero es la entidad que lo firma la que debería transformar el XML a canónico, no tu.

Y aquí viene lo otro extraño: Un XML canónico ordena los `namespace` de forma lexicográfica (luego ordena los otros atributos de igual manera), es decir el orden debería ser:

- cartaporte20
- cfdi
- schemaLocation
- xsi

Por las dudas te dejo un código para convertir el XML a canónico:

```
//Aqui arriba va todo tu código anterior hasta esta línea
var xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlDsigC14NTransform xmlDsigC14NTransform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
xmlDsigC14NTransform.LoadInput(xmlDocument);

var ms = (MemoryStream)xmlDsigC14NTransform.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));
ms.Flush();
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Agradezco sumamente de tu ayuda, la solución rápida y factible fue eliminar el NameSpace que venia desde el MODEL para que así lo colocara al Inicio de XML